# Android Chrome missing polish symbols when font-family: serif

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, fonts, font-family

### Problem

Seems like `font-family: serif` in Chrome on Android renders polish symbols incorrectly.

Everything works as intended in Chrome on Windows.

Here is an example [pen](https://codepen.io/KonradLinkowski/pen/dyzeRKP).

### Question

Is it a known bug? Can it be fixed without adding a custom font and keeping the serif option?

### Screenshots:

| android | windows |
| --- | --- |
| [image: missing polish symbols in font-family serif] | [image] |

Comment: It looks correctly on my Android Chrome 95. However it's not a good idea to leave it just `serif`.  Better choose a default font which contains Polish symbols.

Comment: @Azu the problem originated on the website that I don't have control over. I was trying to investigate the problem and found this bug. The solution I would search for is rather fixing the bug in chrome itself or finding a way to inject a style to this website on the client site.

Comment: If you add Times New Roman to `font-family: serif` that would solve the problem. This font is very old and well supported. Only by using `serif` you allow the browser to apply a default serif font, which might not contain Polish symbols.

Comment: @Azu as I said. I can't alter the css of the webpage.